# How to add a custom datetime column without getting the "not supported in DirectQuery mode" error?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I want to add a column that shows timestamp as a date. In SQL this is a very simple "select X as Y" operation, yet when I do this in PowerBI, I get this error:

> This step results in a query that is not supported in DirectQuery mode

I created the column with this query code:

```
#datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0) + #duration(0,0,0,[timestamp])
```

Where `timestamp` refers to another column that contains UTC timestamps. The entire query then looks like this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(MY_TABLE_NAME_View, "timestamp_date", each #datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0) + #duration(0,0,0,[timestamp]))
```

I want to accomplish this some other way that does not erase the DirectQuery functionality since I am working with a gargantuan table. I suspect the `each` means it actually loops over rows instead of calculating the new column value on demand.

Comment: See this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/native-query-folding